# Why does `Ex` apply to both splits?

Tags: netrw, split

I noticed that when I split multiple times in combination with `Ex`, for example I run the following commands

```
:Sexplore
:q
:Sexplore
```

It will open netrw in both splits. I expected it to only open in the new split. It also changes the color scheme compared to the normal `netrw`. This started happening recently, and my `.vimrc` hasn't changed.

I don't have any custom settings for `netrw` or `Explore`, so I'm assuming this is the default behavior, but I'd like to change this so that `Sexplore` and `Vexplore` always open `netrw` in the new split

Comment: This is a recent bug that is already being handled where it matters, [in the issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/12304).

Comment: That was fixed in Vim Commit: [b7398fe](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/b7398fe41c9e1e731d058105a34158871ee83e3f), so you should update to Vim >= [v9.0.1556](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v9.0.1556)